# Trouble with Dim and CopyDirectory in Visual Basic Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i have this code written in Visual Basic in Visual Studio. For some reason its unable find selected folder through variable. If i print that variable, it says programfiles86 as it should, but looks like its badly used in copydirectory command. Can somebody help me with this problem? I am totaly new in coding..

Class MainWindow

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim PFD As String
    PFD = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("PFD\Torchlight II\TorchTemp_GUTS\", "PFD\Torchlight II\", True)
    Process.Start("PFD\Torchlight II\Editor.exe")
End Sub
```

End Class
&
Debug:
Additional information: Could't find PFD\Torchlight II\TorchTemp_GUTS\ folder.

It should copy files in torchtemp folder into torchlight 2 and then run editor - if there is a better way to do it pleaseee tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `PFD` variable instead of embedding it in the string:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(PFD & "\Torchlight II\TorchTemp_Guts\", _
                                     PFD & "\Torchlight II\", True)
Process.Start(PFD & "\Torchlight II\Editor.exe")
```

(I don't have VB.Net handy. I'm not sure if `Environment.GetFolderPath` includes the final backslash after the path or not. If it does, just remove the first backslash in each reference to `\Torchlight\` above to make it `Torchlight II.)